# Blender C, Object struct name

Tags: development

I try to get my name object from Object struct, but it seem that name doesn't exist in this struct. Where is name of Object. ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: In file "object.h" file, the Object class has a public property called "name". It may be what you want ?

Comment: Humm, i think not. Actually if i create an object type Object : 

Object *obj;

Object come from DNA_object_type.h who doesn't have name. 
Maybe i do it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, After some dumb research, I find ID property who hold basic property like name.

```
Object *obj;
printf("%s", obj.ID.name);
```